# What could be causing my cassandra node to have so many pending tasks?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I'm running a 6 node cassandra cluster on kubernetes.

Recently one the of nodes keeps crashing (or performance degrades to the point it needs to be bounced).

I'm seeing the number of pending tasks steadily rise over time; once it reaches the hundreds then the pod becomes unstable. Running `nodetool tpstats` shows that it is the `MemtableReclaimMemory` with the pending threads.

Additionally the number of file descriptors open on this node is much higher than my other nodes.  Behaving nodes all run at around 990 or so FDs, whilst the problem node is nearly double that and climbs slowly.

We run a nightly backup job starting at 4am (clearsnapshot, snapshot), the exact start time staggered across the nodes.  It's when these jobs start that there is a spike in the number of pending tasks / file descriptors (for non-snapshot data related files - system file descriptors are slowly added).

If the node/pod is bounced then it behaves for a day/ few days and then this pattern starts to repeat itself.

There is a weekly repair job run on a wednesday.

Any ideas what could be causing this or what trouble-shooting next-steps are?  It feels like resources aren't being freed after the snapshotting.

As this is a production database and I'm inexperienced with this technology, I'm unsure which actions (repairs/compactions) are safe to use *live* and those that need to wait until out of hours.

Cassandra 3.11.4
Java 1.8.0_232

[image: grafana file descriptors]

[image: grafana pending tasks]

[image: nodetool tpstats]

Answer (score 1):

There was a corrupted SSTable that I hadn't spotted due to cassandra logs not being correctly forwarded to Kibana.  Once the cassandra node had been repaired, the issue went away.